# Sincronização de Dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server

Boa tarde pessoal. Estou com um pequeno problema: criei uma aplicação em C# para gestão de uma empresa de transportes. Aí eles me pediram que também criasse uma página web de onde o cliente informando o número do seu processo, pudesse ver o andamento da sua mercadoria. Os twits de andamento do processo de um certo cliente são feitos localmente. Portanto, a pergunta é a seguinte: como faço para sincronizar dados de um servidor local (SQL Server no caso) para um servidor web????

Comment: Qual é o sistema operacional onde está o servidor web: GNU/Linux ou Windows? Qual o software do servidor web?

Comment: Simples, o banco tem que ser o mesmo e tem que ser online.

Comment: O Servidor é Windows.